# Change color of control to default

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

i do have a textbox. When there is error i set borderbrush to new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red). When error is fixed, i want to switch to default color of border of a textbox. I am doing it in codebehind not xaml.

However it is system dependent. I noticed there is something like

SystemColor.ActiveControl etc. Should i use these and if yes, which one is default border of textbox?

Also i noticed there is something like Textbox.borderbrushproperty.defaultmetadata.defaultvalue, which i did not manage to work.

Any ideas how to switch to default borderbrush? thank you.

Comment: keep track of what the default color is before you change the color to red.

Comment: Not sure if WPF supports it, but Silverlight has a IDataErrorInfo interface that will put a red box around any control that is bound to a property that has an error.  Perhaps that would be easier than what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just save the initial value at startup and use that?  You should be able to use the system colors, but if you ever change the default color this will continue to work.

```
private Color _defBtnColor;
public MyUserControl()
{
    _defBtnColor = someButton.Foreground;
}  

private void SetBackToDefault()
{
    someButton.Foreground = _defBtnColor;
}
```

Comment: I know that is option, but doesnt work if user switches themes while running application. I know it is rare occasion, but want to have clean solution

Comment: @VojtechRuzicka: That should not be a problem.  By default it will be using a system color, which is dynamic.  If you ever change the default then, well, you changed it for a reason and this still works.  Have you actually tried testing it?  Does it not work if you change the system theme?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to do it in code-behind? If not, you could use a `Trigger` which will only change the border color while the trigger condition is met.

```
<Style x:Key="MyTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl, Path=HasErrors}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: this is by far the best and simplest answer

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
control.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Window);
```

For more information, see [Color.FromKnownColor on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromknowncolor.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm a little late to the party but I think you're asking how to change a color to the system default of control?

```
someControl.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
```

or

```
sslEditMode.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonFace;
```